# How to acquire GIL for the new thread state created using embed python in C++ application

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, numpy, python-c-api

I have a C++ application where we provide a python editor(which uses python 3.7), users can input and execute the python code in the editor. Following is the sample code where we are creating a new thread state and making it current before executing the script provided by users.

```
#include <python.h>

PyThreadState* globalthread;

void executescript()
{
    PyEval_SaveThread();
    PyThreadState* ts = PyThreadState_New(globalthread->interp);
    int gilstate = PyGILState_Check(); //check whether GIL is with current thread or not
    if (!gilstate)
    {
        PyEval_RestoreThread(ts);
    }
    else
    {
        
        PyThreadState_Swap(ts);
    }
    // get the thread state with which GIL is currently assigned
    PyThreadState * gilthreadstate = PyGILState_GetThisThreadState(); 
    //----> the above line return pointer to global thread state (gilthreadstate == globalthread)
    //----> which means the GIL is not acquired by the new current thread
    gilstate = PyGILState_Check(); //results in zero as GIL is not with current thread
    std::string str = "def script():\n\timport sys\n\tsys.path.append('C:\\Python\\Python37\\Lib\\site-packages')\n\tprint(sys.path)\n\timport numpy\n\tarr = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])\n\tprint(arr)\nscript()";
    PyRun_SimpleString(str.c_str());
    PyThreadState_Clear(ts);
    PyThreadState_DeleteCurrent();
    PyEval_RestoreThread(globalthread);
    //following stmt returns 1 as the current thread is global thread and it has GIL with it
    gilstate = PyGILState_Check(); 
}

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyEval_InitThreads();
    globalthread = PyThreadState_Get();
    executescript();
    PyThreadState_Swap(globalthread);
    Py_FinalizeEx();
    return 0;
}
```

The new current thread is not acquiring the GIL when PyEval_RestoreThread or PyThreadState_Swap is called on it.
Python scripts having `import numpy` or `import pandas` will end in deadlock due to this.
Can someone let me know how to acquire GIL for the new thread state or where the code is wrong?

Comment: How does `PyRun_SimpleString()` run Python? What is the callstack of the hang?

Comment: @ThomasWeller `PyRun_SimpleString()` takes a string that has script entered by the user through our editor. Before calling this we initialize the python framework using `Py_Initialize` . As requested the call stack is attached to the question.

Comment: Are you calling `Py_Initialize` multiple times? If so I'm pretty sure this question is yet another duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676314/py-initialize-py-finalize-not-working-twice-with-numpy

Comment: @DavidW `Py_Initialize` is called only once.

Comment: @DavidW, looks like the issue is with the usage of python threads. I will change my question accordingly.

Comment: None of that looks right. `PyEval_ReleaseLock` is deprecated since Python 3.2. `PyEval_SaveThread` and `PyEval_RestoreThread` are usually used as a pair to surround a "no GIL" block but you're doing something else entirely. I just don't understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @DavidW this is the existing code in our application. I'm not sure why it's been done like this(creating a new thread) and I'm new to using embed python. I see after creating a new thread using `PyThreadState_New` and making it as the current thread return `PyGILState_Check` as zero,
I feel this is causing the deadlock. I'm not sure how to pass the GIL to a new thread.

Comment: What is the program supposed to do? Run a script in a separate thread?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yes

Comment: I have edited my question with meaningful description and code

Comment: Perhaps look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595222/multithreading-with-python-and-c-api).

Comment: Creating a separate C++ thread and instantiating PyThreadState in the thread resolved the issue. Thank you @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem for your help.

Answer (score 1):

[Comment by hn-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69895495/how-to-acquire-gil-for-the-new-thread-state-created-using-embed-python-in-c-ap?noredirect=1#comment123583597_69895495) has resolved the issue by creating a new C++ thread.
Here is my modified code.

```
#include <python.h>
#include <thread>
PyThreadState* globalthread;

void execute()
{
    PyThreadState* ts = PyThreadState_New(globalthread->interp);

    int gilstate = PyGILState_Check();
    if (!gilstate)
    {
        PyEval_RestoreThread(ts);
    }
    else
    {

        PyThreadState_Swap(ts);
    }
    std::string str = "def script():\n\timport sys\n\tsys.path.append('C:\\Python\\Python37\\Lib\\site-packages')\n\tprint(sys.path)\n\timport numpy\n\tarr = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])\n\tprint(arr)\nscript()";
    PyRun_SimpleString(str.c_str());
    PyThreadState_Clear(ts);
    PyThreadState_DeleteCurrent();
}

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    globalthread = PyThreadState_Get();
    PyEval_SaveThread();
    std::thread t(executePythonScript);
    t.join();
    PyEval_RestoreThread(globalthread);
    //PyThreadState_Swap(globalthread);
    Py_FinalizeEx();
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for pointing out the post.